# How is the LCD on STM32H735G-DK connected, and how can I turn it off?

Tags: stm32, embedded, lcd, gpio

The STM32H735G-DK Discovery board comes with an LCD.  I wrote from scratch (no HAL) a simple blinky code, and it works well.  However, the LCD is on (and backlit) by default, without any code from me to do so.

I'd like to turn it off.  Yet, I can find no information as to how the display is wired to the MCU and what I need to do to turn it off.  In fact, given ST's default of "everything, even a clock, is off until you turn it on," I'm surprised the LCD is on by default.

I found this https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/stm32h735g-dk-bsp/blob/main/stm32h735g_discovery_lcd.c

```
    __HAL_LTDC_DISABLE(&hlcd_ltdc);
    /* Assert LCD_DISP_CTRL_EN pin */
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LCD_DISP_CTRL_GPIO_PORT, LCD_DISP_CTRL_PIN, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
   /* Assert LCD_BL_CTRL pin */
      HAL_GPIO_WritePin(LCD_BL_CTRL_GPIO_PORT, LCD_BL_CTRL_PIN, GPIO_PIN_RESET);
```

which, excerpting out, indicates I can shut the backlight by clearing the appropriate pin, which [should be[(https://github.com/STMicroelectronics/stm32h735g-dk-bsp/blob/b31a20380749046460aad937c6d0177cd170ce80/stm32h735g_discovery_lcd.h#L75) G15:

```
/* Back-light control pin */
#define LCD_BL_CTRL_PIN                       GPIO_PIN_15
#define LCD_BL_CTRL_GPIO_PORT                 GPIOG
```

But of course, just clearing GPIO G15 does nothing, which makes sense, because I never enabled GPIOG or its RCC.

It wouldn't make sense that I need to enable GPIOG and its RCC just to clear it - aren't GPIO outputs off by default?

Therefore: What's a barebones way to turn off this LCD? How is it wired, and why is on (or at least backlit) by default, even after reset (or full power cycle)?

---

For reference, here is what I see in the [schematic](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/layouts_and_diagrams/schematic_pack/group1/cb/24/7b/09/9b/4e/46/0d/MB1520-H735I-B02_Schematic/files/MB1520-H735I-B02_Schematic.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.MB1520-H735I-B02_Schematic.pdf)

[image]

and, with Justme's help, is the relevant pullup:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The LCD backlight enable is controlled by PORTG pin 15, or PG15 in short.

The MCU pins are not outputs unless configured.

The LCD board pulls the line high with a resistor, which by default turns it on.

In order to turn it off, you need to configure PG15 as output and make sure it is at logic low level. In order to do that, you really do need to initialize all required clocks properly on all buses on the path to GPIOG peripheral, including the peripheral clock itself.

As the LCD module is completely external and unrelated to the MCU, assuming that everything is off doesn't apply any more, even if everything inside the MCU is turned off.

Comment: Thank you.  This worked perfect.   I understand from your answer that the board has a pull up resistor connected to LCD_BL, and I need to actively pull it down - thus, keeping the LCD BL off must draw current.  Where is this documented? Or, how could I figure something like this out myself in the future?

Comment: It's in the Discovery board schematics, in the LCD adapter board section. So it's not on the MCU board and not on the LCD module.

Comment: @SRobertJames That is the Discovery Board schematics and that's the connector which connects to the LCD board. So you won't find it in the Discovery Board schematics, but on the LCD board schematics, available as a separate file in the Discovery Board schematics section, as it is a common LCD board for other Discovery Boards.

Comment: @SRobertJames ST website, on the page of your Discovery board, in the Schematic Pack category of CAD Resources, board name MB1315, resistor R6 on boost converter U4.

Answer (score 0):

The [ST User manual for STM32H735G-DK](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/um2679-discovery-kit-with-stm32h735ig-mcu-stmicroelectronics.pdf) gives the following:

> **7.1 TFT color LCD 480x272 pixels**
> The STM32H735G-DK board includes a 4.3-inch 480x272 LCD-TFT board (MB1315), which is connected to the
> RGB interface of the STM32H735IGK6 through a 50-pin connector (CN19). The MB1315 LCD board uses the
> RK043FN48H-CT672B TFT-LCD from Rocktech with the driving system, white LED backlight, and capacitive
> touch panel.
>
> The touchscreen controller interfaces with the STM32H735IGK6 via the bidirectional I2C4 bus, since the TFT
> LCD reset is controlled by PH6 GPIO (LCD_RST signal) in the default configuration where SB43 is ON and
> SB44 is OFF. The possibility to control the LCD reset by the NRST general reset is also available on the
> STM32H735G-DK board. In this case, SB44 must be ON and SB43 OFF

Additionally, table 8.8 gives the connections to the LCD, including:

- PG15 LCD_BL_CTRL
- PH6 LCD_RST
- PD10 LCD_DISP

The circuit diagram gives the connections:

[image]
*From [ST MB1315 circuit diagram](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/layouts_and_diagrams/schematic_pack/group1/f1/b0/16/03/d0/57/4b/66/MB1315-Default-A02_Schematic/files/MB1315-Default-A02_Schematic.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.MB1315-Default-A02_Schematic.pdf)*

You can find out the individual functions from the [Display Datasheet](https://www.nxp.com/docs/en/supporting-information/RK043FN02H-CT.pdf)